# Combination of add_months and to_date gone wrong if date is 28-Feb

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to get a date of 16 days before of `6 months +  given date`. Now that's a simple task. I've created a query to get the result. But yesterday I entered 28-Feb-2019 and answer gone wrong. I tried to find solution but failed. So please, help me out I'm providing two saperate queries to find the answer.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:P2_JOIN_DT,'DD-MON-RRRR')-16,6)) FROM DUAL;
```

Execute above query and compare date 01-MAR(or any march date) with 01_JAN(or any other month). Need to get value 16-(month + 6).

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(:P2_JOIN_DT,'DD-MON-RRRR'),6)-16)) FROM DUAL;
```

Now, execute this query and compare 28-FEB with any 28-(month).

Other dates are working right.

Actually what is happening, I've created an oracle-apex web-application where, after every month (and one day before) user can give ratings for a particular task (this dates are also displayed on screen). Task is simple so whenever this due date occures field becomes editable otherwise it will be read-only or disabled. But after every 6th month, field must be enable before 15 days of displayed due date. Now here, task gets quite confusing. because finding 1 day early date makes sence (in case of 28-FEB, I get 27) but after 6th month where displayed due date is 27-aug field has to be enabled on 12-aug (15 days before of displayed due date). So, for displaying I used normal query by subtracting only 1 day, but for enablling field I've to subtract 16 days on 6th month.

So that's why I've provided 2 queries. one of them works for 28-feb but if date is 1-march then query fails, and another works for 1-march but failed on 28-feb

But this causes a fault in my system.

Please help me to get rid out of this.

Comment: Its working fine
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('28-FEB-19','DD-MON-RRRR')-16,6)) FROM DUAL;
Gives
12-AUG-19
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('28-MAR-19','DD-MON-RRRR')-16,6)) FROM DUAL;
12-SEP-19

Comment: Adding a number of months is *not* a simple task because it depends on what you mean by that. There are some edge cases (particularly with dates in the last few days of a month, and especially with dates like 28 and 29 February in leap years) where "adding a month" is ambiguous. More to the point, the answer will potentially be different depending on whether you add the months first followed by adding the days, or if you add the days and then add the months.

Comment: For example, date'2000-02-28'+6 months results in 28/8/2000, whereas date'2001-02-28'+6 months results in 31/8/2001. There is no single "right" answer, it just depends on your definition of the requirements.

Comment: Your two queries give different results anyway; 2019-03-01 becomes either 2019-08-13 or 2019-08-16. You need to define what you actually want to happen.

Comment: I've edited the question, kindly check, so you will understand my current scenario.

Comment: After your edit I think the `case` approach will work; if it doesn't can you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query is subtracting 16 days (which may take you into the previous month) and then adds six months to that. Your second query add six months (which seems to be tripping you up at month end, as other have pointed out.

You seem to want to different queries at different points in the month; so you could combine both calculations in a case expression:

```
case when extract(day from p2_join_dt) > 16
  then
    add_months(p2_join_dt - 16, 6)
  else
    add_months(p2_join_dt, 6) - 16
end
```

If the original date is after the 16th day of the month, then subtracting 16 days leaves you in the same month, so you can then add six months to that. If the original date is on or before the 16th then subtracting 16 days would put you in the previous month, which you want to avoid (I think!); but for those you can add six months first, and then do the subtraction.

Demo with some sample dates of the 1st and 28th of each month this year, and showing the results of both your original queries separately for comparison:

```
with cte (p2_join_dt) as (
  select date '2019-01-01' + (level - 1) * interval '1' month
  from dual
  connect by level <= 12
  union all
  select date '2019-01-28' + (level - 1) * interval '1' month
  from dual
  connect by level <= 12
)
select p2_join_dt,
  add_months(p2_join_dt - 16, 6) as query1,
  add_months(p2_join_dt, 6) - 16 as query2,
  case
    when extract(day from p2_join_dt) > 16 then
      add_months(p2_join_dt - 16, 6)
    else
      add_months(p2_join_dt, 6) - 16
  end as combined
from cte
order by p2_join_dt;
```

which gives:

```
P2_JOIN_DT QUERY1     QUERY2     COMBINED  
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2019-01-01 2019-06-16 2019-06-15 2019-06-15
2019-01-28 2019-07-12 2019-07-12 2019-07-12
2019-02-01 2019-07-16 2019-07-16 2019-07-16
2019-02-28 2019-08-12 2019-08-15 2019-08-12
2019-03-01 2019-08-13 2019-08-16 2019-08-16
2019-03-28 2019-09-12 2019-09-12 2019-09-12
2019-04-01 2019-09-16 2019-09-15 2019-09-15
2019-04-28 2019-10-12 2019-10-12 2019-10-12
2019-05-01 2019-10-15 2019-10-16 2019-10-16
2019-05-28 2019-11-12 2019-11-12 2019-11-12
2019-06-01 2019-11-16 2019-11-15 2019-11-15
2019-06-28 2019-12-12 2019-12-12 2019-12-12
2019-07-01 2019-12-15 2019-12-16 2019-12-16
2019-07-28 2020-01-12 2020-01-12 2020-01-12
2019-08-01 2020-01-16 2020-01-16 2020-01-16
2019-08-28 2020-02-12 2020-02-12 2020-02-12
2019-09-01 2020-02-16 2020-02-14 2020-02-14
2019-09-28 2020-03-12 2020-03-12 2020-03-12
2019-10-01 2020-03-15 2020-03-16 2020-03-16
2019-10-28 2020-04-12 2020-04-12 2020-04-12
2019-11-01 2020-04-16 2020-04-15 2020-04-15
2019-11-28 2020-05-12 2020-05-12 2020-05-12
2019-12-01 2020-05-15 2020-05-16 2020-05-16
2019-12-28 2020-06-12 2020-06-12 2020-06-12
```

Answer (score 1):

I think to avoid such problem you can add months in truncated date to month and adding days again like following:

```
add_months(trunc(:P2_JOIN_DT, 'month'), 6) + extract(day from :P2_JOIN_DT) + 16
```

Cheers!!

Comment: `- 16`, not `+ 16`? Actually you need another `- 1` as well I think - since you're now effectively including the first day of the month twice. Nice though.

Answer (score 0):

"6 months + given date" is

```
add_months(given_date, 6)
```

"16 days before of *6 months + given date*" is

```
add_months(given_date, 6) - 16
```

For example:

```
SQL> select add_months(date '2019-02-28', 6) - 16 res1,
  2         add_months(date '2019-03-28', 6) - 16 res2
  3  from dual;

RES1       RES2
---------- ----------
15.08.2019 12.09.2019

SQL>
```

Comment: Try 28-FEB and then try 28-MAR values were quite different.

Comment: Values should be different, shouldn't they? I've added an example. If it isn't OK, could you post some examples as pairs of `given date : desired result` which might help us help you?

Comment: look after 6 months of 28-feb date will 28-aug right? so, 16 days before of 28-aug will be 12 aug !

Comment: Wrong. 6 months after 28-feb is **31-aug**, not 28-aug. This is how `add_months` works, see documentation. "If date is the last day of the month or if the resulting month has fewer days than the day component of date, then the result is the last day of the resulting month" (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions004.htm#SQLRF00603):

> If date is the last day of the month (...) then the result is the last
>   day of the resulting month.

So:

```
select add_months(date '2019-02-28', 6) from dual
```

returns date `2019-08-31`, not `2019-08-28` as you expected.